# How to pass data from ViewDidLoad to a function of a button

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have two Random numbers generating in ViewDidLoad. I Want to plus these two numbers and the result should be checked in a button with data of a input field. my problem is that I do not know how to transfer result to the function CheckResultBtn . now it does not recognise result.

here is My codes and I really appreciate any kinds of help

```
 class ViewController: UIViewController {



    @IBOutlet weak var lblRandomNumOne: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblRandomNumTwo: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var KidsField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var Showresult: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var CheckResult: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


        let x = Int.random(in: 0 ..< 10)
        lblRandomNumOne.text = String(x);


        let y = Int.random(in: 0 ..< 10)
        lblRandomNumTwo.text = String(y);

        let result = x + y;  
        CheckResultBtn(result) //not sure about this 


       }


    @IBAction func CheckResultBtn(_ sender: Any)
    {

        if (KidsField != nil)
        {
            let kidsresult = Int(KidsField.text!) ;

            if (result == kidsresult)
            {

                Showresult.text = "Bravo";

            }
            else
            {
                Showresult.text = "Try Again!"
            }

        }
    }



}
```

Comment: Create a variable right under the class name.

Comment: @ElTomato can you explain more?

Comment: var randomNumber1: Int?;var randomNumber2: Int?

Comment: what is this ? `KidsField` is it a textfield ?

Comment: @ElTomato please answer I am new to swift and a little confused

Comment: @Vicky_Vignesh yes it is a text field . thank you fo your care

Comment: Being new is not an excuse.  If that's too difficult to understand, you may want to read a book or two.

Comment: start variable names with lower case letter

Answer (score -1, accepted):

create a new function instead of using action Method 
like this :

```
func CheckResultBtn(_ result : Int) {

        if (KidsField != nil)
        {
            let kidsresult = Int(KidsField.text!) ;

            if (result == kidsresult)
            {

                Showresult.text = "Bravo";

            }
            else
            {
                Showresult.text = "Try Again!"
            }

        }
    }
```

or create a variable

```
var result : Int?
```

assign a value 
        result = x + y;

and use inside the action Method

```
var result : Int?
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let x = Int.random(in: 0 ..< 10)
    lblRandomNumOne.text = String(x);


    let y = Int.random(in: 0 ..< 10)
    lblRandomNumTwo.text = String(y);

    result = x + y;
}


@IBAction func CheckResultBtn(_ sender: Any) {
    if (KidsField != nil)
    {
        let kidsresult = Int(KidsField.text!) ;

        if (result == kidsresult)
        {

            Showresult.text = "Bravo";

        }
        else
        {
            Showresult.text = "Try Again!"
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: @Sh_Khan created a function not an action Method.

Comment: should var result : Int? and result = x+y replace in ViewdidLoad?

Comment: outside the function method result : Int? and  use inside the viewDidLoad result = x+y, check my updated code

Comment: I am not voting yet . let me check it please

Comment: I tried the next suggestion and it throw an error Thread 1: signal SIGABRT somewhere in this code class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

Comment: what is this `if (KidsField != nil)` it's a very horrible line , this should be downvoted plus the question op

Comment: @Sh_Khan just provide the answer of the problem not modify the code, i know code quality is not good but it is depend on developer not us.

Answer (score 1):

declare the variable "result" before the viewDidload function

```
var result : Int!
```

then proceed to perform the operation on the variable in your viewDidload and  you can get rid of this line

```
CheckResultBtn(result)
```

and you should be able to access the result variable in your  IBAction function

Comment: seems easy . but let me check it

Comment: I dont know why but it crashed.

Comment: some problem in the background of codes here class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {....

Comment: can you post the exact error it showed? also I hope you  removed the "let"

Comment: Thank you it seems it was the answer too. but other one helped me more by details and also he posted the answer sooner. Sorry but I vote it. thank you again

Comment: Exactly let was the problem. Thank you very very much

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
@IBAction func checkResultBtn(_ sender: Any)  {   
   displayRes(Int(kidsField.text!)!)
}  
func displayRes(_ result:Int)    {  
   showresult.text = result == kidsresult ? "Bravo" : "Try Again!" 
}
```

Then inside `viewDidLoad`

```
displayRes(x+y)
```

Comment: seems great. but give me time to check it.

Comment: it's `Showresult` in your code above disconnect the outlet and rename it if you need it in a standard swifty naming convention

Comment: ok understand. this line of code has error so I am confused a little showresult.text = result == kidsresult ? "Bravo" : "Try Again!"  , let me work more on it

Comment: displayRes(Int(kidsField.text!)!) is a very coding style, use guard or let for better handling.